# Replace all spaces which are enclosed within braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

What I want to do is find all spaces that are enclosed in braces, and then replace them with another character.

Something like:

```
{The quick brown} fox jumps {over the lazy} dog
```

To change into:

```
{The*quick*brown} fox jumps {over*the*lazy} dog
```

I already searched online, but only this is what I got so far, and it seems so close to what I really want.

```
preg_replace('/(?<={)[^}]+(?=})/','*',$string);
```

My problem with the above code is that it replaces everything:

```
{*} fox jumps {*} dog
```

I was looking into regexp tutorials to figure out how i should modify the above code to only replace spaces but to no avail. Any input will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just string explode between the spaces and then cat the resulting array back together with "*" in between. Sorry I'm too tired to write an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all braces are correctly nested, and that there are no nested braces, you can do this using a lookahead assertion:

```
$result = preg_replace('/ (?=[^{}]*\})/', '*', $subject);
```

This matches and replaces a space only if the next brace is a closing brace:

```
(?=     # Assert that the following regex can be matched here:
 [^{}]* #  - Any number of characters except braces
 \}     #  - A closing brace
)       # End of lookahead
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked brilliantly. However, I am trying a solution using php string functions (strpos, substr, etc). Do you still advice using regex? I have read about regex being slow and such.

Comment: @Bibokid: You could profile Zaffy's and my solution and find out - regular expressions are not necessarily slow (but often they are constructed very sloppily, making them slow because they have to brute-force a solution when a clever solution is also available). In many cases, regex libraries are highly optimized and can be much faster than any solution you construct yourself using string functions.

Answer (score 2):

I am reacting to your comment that you dont want to use regex, just string manipulation. That's OK but why have you then written that you are looking for a regex?

Solution wihout regex:

```
<?php

$str = "{The quick brown} fox jumps {over the lazy} dog";

for($i = 0, $b = false, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; $i++)
{ 
    switch($str[$i])
    {
        case '{': $b = true; continue;
        case '}': $b = false; continue;
        default:
        if($b && $str[$i] == ' ')
            $str[$i] = '*';
    }
}

print $str;

?>
```

Comment: It was just that while i was waiting for a response here in stackoverflow, I was experimenting with a non-regex solution that came into my head. Thank you for this, I will give this a try too.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$a = '{The quick brown} fox jumps {over the lazy} dog';
$b = preg_replace_callback('/\{[^}]+\}/sim', function($m) {
    return str_replace(' ', '*', $m[0]);
}, $a);
var_dump($b); // output: string(47) "{The*quick*brown} fox jumps {over*the*lazy} dog"
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this too and compare with the other solutions.